# equal values and uniqueness

Tags: unique, julia

I have a self defined type called *Dyad*, that consists of two variables, *src*, and *dst*. I have redefined the equal sign for dyads, such that

```
Dyad(1,2) == Dyad(2,1)
>true
```

However if I define the following Dyad vector

```
d = [Dyad(1,2), Dyad(2,1)]
unique(d) == d
>true
```

Do  I need to redefine my equality so that *unique()* understands this?

P.S this is how I defined my equality:

```
==(x::Dyad, y::Dyad) = (x.src == y.src && x.dst == y.dst) || (x.src == y.dst && x.dst == y.src)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably it is even simpler to define `hash` for `Dyad`:

`hash(x::Dyad, h::UInt) = hash(minmax(x.src, x.dst), h)`

to get what you want. In this way you ensure that all functions testing for equality using `hash` in the process will work correctly.

EDIT: `minmax` will be better than `extrema` here.

Comment: Is `any(y->y==x, s)` implemented with `O(1)` complexity?

Comment: Seems nor `any(y->y==d[1], d)` nor `d[1] in Set(d)` is `O(1)` in Julia today although python's `key in Set` is `O(1)` (see [doc](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)). But hash solution has better chance to be `O(1)` in future implementations...

Comment: `key in Set` is O(1) in my opinion - as it calls `ht_keyindex` in the end. This is one of the benefits of defining `hash`. The other benefit is that if you define `Dyad` as immutable you can safely store it in `Set` or use as key in `Dict`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how well I can explain this but I'll give it a shot.

Basically `unique` iterates over all of the values you give it and tests if `value in seen_values` (if not then the value is appended to the list of values to be returned). However `seen_values` here is of type `Set` and `in(x, s::Set)` has a different definition to `in(x, a::AbstractArray)`. In the `Set` version of `in` the `==` operator is not used to define equality. To get around this we can define a specialised version of `in` for the `Dyad` type. See below for the code (which will also show you the relevant lines in the source of `Base`).

```
type Dyad
    src::Int
    dst::Int
end
import Base.==
==(x::Dyad, y::Dyad) = (x.src == y.src && x.dst == y.dst) || (x.src == y.dst && x.dst == y.src)

d = [Dyad(1,2), Dyad(2,1)]

# @show unique(d) # hmmm... if you uncomment this line it won't work
#                 (I guess because unique will be already compiled...)

@show in(d[1], [d[2]])
@which in(d[1], [d[2]])

@show in(d[1], Set([d[2]]))
@which in(d[1], Set([d[2]]))

import Base.in
in(x::Dyad, s::Set) = any(y->y==x, s)

@show unique(d) ## Yay! it works
```

Comment: Thanks, this was actually very helpful